# Tensorflow slower than scipy and nested for loops

Tags: tensorflow, scipy

I have an input tensor of shape **11x11x4** and 2 kernels of shape **5x5x4**. I am trying to correlate(convolve) them. I used `scipy.signal.correlate`, `tensorflow.nn.conv2d` and a nested for loop with element wise multiplication of 3D numpy arrays. Time taken for this operation looks like:
**time(scipy)< time(nested for loop) << time(tensorflow)**. Corresponding code and timing plots can be found in this [jupyter notebook](https://bitbucket.org/ruthvik92/me571/src/6a919c7bfd964786636eb8396d9024bce4470c68/project/numpy_conv.ipynb?at=master&fileviewer=notebook-viewer%3Anbviewer). Please scroll to **Timing Analysis** section. Surprisingly, tensorflow did worse than nested for loop. Am i doing something wrong here? Or Am I comparing apples and oranges? If yes, what operations on tensforflow am I supposed to use in order to setup a fair competition? I am not using GPUs.

Comment: Have you tried the calculation with bigger inputs?  Try a *much* bigger input tensor.

Comment: TF does perform the best when i use an input tensor of size 121x121x5. So do i have to have both the methods in my application?
One for smaller and the other for larger tensors?